# how reserve height while display is none

Tags: css

I have a div with default display:none. how do I reserve the height so when the div shows, it does not reshift the elements around it? thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Instead of putting `display: none;` on your div, put `visibility: hidden;`. It will be invisible, but still take up space.

Answer (score 4):

Use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`. Your element won't display, but its dimensions still apply and affect other elements because it's still a part of the page flow.

Answer (score 4):

if you can use visiblity hidden property instead of display:none you can achieve what you want.

When you do visibilty:hidden it just make the elements opacity to 0 while the element is still retaining its space.

Answer (score 2):

Or if you are playing with jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut and need that spot to remain empty but with reserved height, then just wrap around needed element  with fixed height, for example:

```
<div style="height: 52px;">
     <img id="loader" src="loader.gif />
</div>
```